# Just removed system-reserved-drive, can't boot into Ubuntu 14.04 anymore

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, hp, boot-repair

I was using **Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1** on my HP Probook 4540. Today I **removed my System Reserved partition** and formatted the Windows partition.

Now, every time I try to boot up my machine, the following error message appears and if I press `Enter`, it starts some kind of memory diagnostic which leads nowhere.

```
Boot device not found. 
Please install an operating system on your hard disk. 

Hard disk - ( 3F0 ). 
For more information, please visit: www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup
```

I have tried a few boot-repairs, used a LiveCD and followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). But they don't seem to help.

Here goes the [boot info summary](http://paste2.org/ayabbkvZ).

How can I make Ubuntu bootable again?

Comment: You will have to describe exactly what goes wrong when you try to boot.

Comment: Boot device not found. Please install an operating system on your hard disk. Hard disk - ( 3F0 ). For more information, please visit:  www.hp.com/go/techcenter/startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone. I would like to share a solution that worked for me. But first let me define what was actually causing this issue.

**Problem:**

Before deletion of *System Reserved* partition, my partitions were organized as follows:

- System Reserved (NTFS),
- Partition 2 (NTFS),
- A block of two EXT4 partitions (a *root* and a *home* partition),
- Partition 4 (NTFS)

[image: This figure shows how it looked before]

When I deleted System Reserved, only one partition was left with a **boot flag** i.e. one of EXT4 partitions. But since this flag was on the root partition and thus was not visible in the first tier of partitions (an NTFS, another NTFS, a block of EXT4s and another NTFS), the system was giving a "Boot device not found" error.

**Solution:**

The following set of step helped me solve this problem:

1. Create a LiveCD of Ubuntu on a USB drive/CD
2. Boot from that drive and select **Try Ubuntu**
3. Use **gparted** to change the flag of the whole block of EXT4 partitions (or whole ubuntu partition; shaded as grey in the figure) to **boot**, this will make sure that a drive with a **boot** flag is visible in the very first tier of partitions

[image: This figure shows how it looks now]

Comment: Ahh, yes.. you can thank HP for this foolishness: the bios is not supposed to know or care about the boot flag ( nobody does except for the DOS/Windows MBR boot code ), but every now and then some manufacturer decides they think they know better.